# why is the counter page being retrieved fully from the server every time it's accessed in a Blazor web application in auto rendermode in .NET 8.0?

Tags: visual-studio, blazor

I created a new Blazor web app using the project template in Visual Studio and .NET 8.0. I noticed the counter page which is in the client project, keeps being retrieved fully from the web server even though it has the '@rendermode InteractiveAuto' attribute. This is evidenced from devtools Network tab and using a network sniffer.
My understanding of the auto render mode is that a page is retrieved from the web server the first time using Blazor server and when the browser gets all the wasm files and assemblies, subsequent requests for any auto render page will be served within the app in the browser. No more Blazor server circuit usage.

Why is the counter page not following this render pattern?

Comment: In all three Auto modes for the sake of user experience they render on the server first as static html. Auto mode runs the component as InteractiveServer first time then InteractiveWebAssembly on subsequent views after the WASM files have been delivered to the client. All three render modes have a constructor with a parameter to prevent the server static rendering.

Comment: I am asking why the auto page is rendering from the server EVERY time. Why isn't it rendering as wasm in subsequent calls. BTW the first call is supposed to be server and interactive. Not static. The user should be able to interact fast through a circuit.

Comment: All interactive modes render static first.

Comment: Regardless, I am not concerned with the first render. I stated this already. I am asking about subsequent requests whose responses always come back from the server.